# H10 Heroku App crashed when I try to deploy

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, heroku, deployment

I'm having the following error message:

> at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
> host=pets-vs-dogs.herokuapp.com
> request_id=e191ffa5-3d2d-4ba5-a70f-e5eab32213d8 fwd="181.46.165.15"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

This happens when I try to deploy my project to Heroku,I even tried to only deploy a "hello world" and got the same message.

In case you want, you can find my code [here](https://github.com/exequielmoneva/cats-vs-dogs)

UPDATE:
HERE'S THE FULL LOG

> 2020-07-21T17:13:34.866583+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:49.120815+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
> command `gunicorn app:app`
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:52.011195+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 1
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:52.052869+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
> starting to crashed
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:52.055989+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
> crashed to starting
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.736140+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:13:51
> +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.737227+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:13:51
> +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:26985 (4)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.737435+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:13:51
> +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.744894+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:13:51
> +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760039+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:13:51
> +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760041+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent
> call last):
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760041+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
> line 583, in spawn_worker
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760042+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760042+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
> line 119, in init_process
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760043+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760043+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
> line 144, in load_wsgi
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760044+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi =
> self.app.wsgi()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760044+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py",
> line 67, in wsgi
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760044+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable =
> self.load()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760045+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
> line 49, in load
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760045+00:00 app[web.1]:     return
> self.load_wsgiapp()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760046+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
> line 39, in load_wsgiapp
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760046+00:00 app[web.1]:     return
> util.import_app(self.app_uri)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760047+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py",
> line 358, in import_app
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760047+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod =
> importlib.import_module(module)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760047+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 127,
> in import_module
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760048+00:00 app[web.1]:     return
> _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760048+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760049+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760049+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760315+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No
> module named 'app'
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.760859+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:13:51
> +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.831011+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:13:51
> +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843563+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:13:51
> +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843565+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent
> call last):
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843566+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
> line 583, in spawn_worker
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843566+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843566+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
> line 119, in init_process
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843567+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843567+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
> line 144, in load_wsgi
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843568+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi =
> self.app.wsgi()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843568+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py",
> line 67, in wsgi
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843569+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable =
> self.load()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843569+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
> line 49, in load
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843569+00:00 app[web.1]:     return
> self.load_wsgiapp()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843570+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
> line 39, in load_wsgiapp
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843570+00:00 app[web.1]:     return
> util.import_app(self.app_uri)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843571+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py",
> line 358, in import_app
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843571+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod =
> importlib.import_module(module)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843572+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 127,
> in import_module
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843572+00:00 app[web.1]:     return
> _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843573+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843573+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843573+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.843676+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No
> module named 'app'
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.844036+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:13:51
> +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.914199+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent
> call last):
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.914285+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
> line 202, in run
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.914955+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.manage_workers()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.914991+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
> line 545, in manage_workers
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.915633+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.spawn_workers()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.915666+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
> line 617, in spawn_workers
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.916296+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1 *
> random.random())
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.916328+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
> line 242, in handle_chld
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.916828+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.916859+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
> line 525, in reap_workers
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.917420+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise
> HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.917654+00:00 app[web.1]:
> gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.917700+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.917701+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the
> above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.917701+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.917751+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent
> call last):
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.917782+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.918130+00:00 app[web.1]:     sys.exit(run())
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.918164+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
> line 58, in run
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.918558+00:00 app[web.1]:
> WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.918589+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py",
> line 228, in run
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.919067+00:00 app[web.1]:     super().run()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.919097+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py",
> line 72, in run
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.919427+00:00 app[web.1]:     Arbiter(self).run()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.919458+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
> line 229, in run
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.919876+00:00 app[web.1]:
> self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.919903+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
> line 342, in halt
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.920343+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.stop()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.920344+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
> line 393, in stop
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.920754+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.920755+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
> line 242, in handle_chld
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.920969+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.921050+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
> line 525, in reap_workers
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.921391+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise
> HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:13:51.921445+00:00 app[web.1]:
> gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:05.395374+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
> command `gunicorn app:app`
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.954643+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 3
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:08.017269+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
> starting to crashed
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.713110+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:14:07
> +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.713761+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:14:07
> +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:10104 (4)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.713883+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:14:07
> +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.718070+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:14:07
> +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723100+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:14:07
> +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723101+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent
> call last):
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723102+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
> line 583, in spawn_worker
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723103+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723103+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
> line 119, in init_process
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723103+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723104+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
> line 144, in load_wsgi
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723104+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi =
> self.app.wsgi()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723105+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py",
> line 67, in wsgi
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723105+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable =
> self.load()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723106+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
> line 49, in load
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723106+00:00 app[web.1]:     return
> self.load_wsgiapp()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723106+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
> line 39, in load_wsgiapp
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723107+00:00 app[web.1]:     return
> util.import_app(self.app_uri)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723107+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py",
> line 358, in import_app
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723108+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod =
> importlib.import_module(module)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723108+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 127,
> in import_module
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723108+00:00 app[web.1]:     return
> _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723109+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723109+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723110+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723110+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No
> module named 'app'
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.723235+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:14:07
> +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.742951+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:14:07
> +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750216+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:14:07
> +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750217+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent
> call last):
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750218+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
> line 583, in spawn_worker
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750219+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750219+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
> line 119, in init_process
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750219+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750220+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
> line 144, in load_wsgi
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750220+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi =
> self.app.wsgi()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750221+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py",
> line 67, in wsgi
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750221+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable =
> self.load()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750221+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
> line 49, in load
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750222+00:00 app[web.1]:     return
> self.load_wsgiapp()
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750222+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
> line 39, in load_wsgiapp
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750223+00:00 app[web.1]:     return
> util.import_app(self.app_uri)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750223+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py",
> line 358, in import_app
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750224+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod =
> importlib.import_module(module)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750224+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 127,
> in import_module
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750224+00:00 app[web.1]:     return
> _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750225+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750225+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750226+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750226+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No
> module named 'app'
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.750392+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:14:07
> +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.857960+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:14:07
> +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:07.858054+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-21 17:14:07
> +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
>
> 2020-07-21T17:14:10.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

Comment: Does the app print out anything else? If so, can you please post the whole log file?

Comment: I'm updating this question, Now the logs are longer

Comment: Do you intend to run your server on a local development on Microsoft Windows?

Comment: Hi, It works perfectly at localhost in my ubuntu PC.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by changing my Procfile.
Now is

> web: python classifier/app.py